# Check if value entered exists in database android

Tags: java, android, database

I want to check if the Username&Password that the user entered exists in the database
I have tried this code, but i don't get it how to work with the cursor and what I'm doing wrong.

```
package com.example.nir.nestleapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MyDBHandler Newdb;
    private SQLiteDatabase _database = null;
    private MyDBHandler  _dbHelper = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        Newdb = new MyDBHandler(this);
        _dbHelper = new MyDBHandler(getApplicationContext());
        _database = this.openOrCreateDatabase(MyDBHandler.DATABASE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        SQLiteDatabase database=_dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        final ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        final TextView RegisterPage=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        TextView Text1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        Button Login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.LoginBtn);
        Button GuestLogin=(Button)findViewById(R.id.LoginGuestBtn);
        final EditText LoginUser=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.LoginUser);
        final EditText LoginPass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.LoginPassword);
        RegisterPage.setTextSize(17);
        Text1.setTextSize(17);
        RegisterPage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,RegisterActivity.class));
            }
        });
        GuestLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainPageActivity.class));
            }
        });
        Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + MyDBHandler.Table_Name, null);
        if (c == null) return;
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            while ( !c.isAfterLast() ) {
                list.add(c.getString(0));
                list.add(c.getString(1));
                c.moveToNext();
            }
        }
        Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(LoginUser.getText().toString().isEmpty()||LoginPass.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if(list.contains(LoginUser.getText().toString())&&list.contains(LoginPass.getText().toString()))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainPageActivity.class));
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is my DBHelper:

```
package com.example.nir.nestleapp;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "UsersTable.db";
    public static final String Table_Name = "UsersTable";
    public static final String KEY_User = "User";
    public static final String KEY_Password = "Password";
    public static final String KEY_FullName = "FullName";
    public static final String KEY_PhoneNumber="PhoneNumber";
    public static final String KEY_IDNUMBER="IDNumber";
    public static final String[] DB_COL = new String[]{KEY_User,KEY_Password,KEY_FullName,KEY_PhoneNumber,KEY_IDNUMBER};

    public MyDBHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CreateTableSql = "Create Table " + Table_Name + " ( " +
                KEY_User + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , " +
                KEY_Password + " TEXT , " +
                KEY_FullName + " TEXT , "+
                KEY_PhoneNumber+" TEXT , "+
                KEY_IDNUMBER+ " ) ";
        db.execSQL(CreateTableSql);
    }@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Table_Name);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void Add(UserTable NewUser) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_User,NewUser.GetUserName() );
        values.put(KEY_Password, NewUser.GetPassword());
        values.put(KEY_FullName,NewUser.GetFullName());
        values.put(KEY_PhoneNumber,NewUser.GetPhoneNumber());
        values.put(KEY_IDNUMBER,NewUser.GetID());
        db.insert(Table_Name, null, values);
        db.close();
    }


}
```

Updated LoginActivity

```
package com.example.nir.nestleapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MyDBHandler Newdb;
    private SQLiteDatabase _database = null;
    private MyDBHandler  _dbHelper = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        Newdb = new MyDBHandler(this);
        _dbHelper = new MyDBHandler(getApplicationContext());
        _database = this.openOrCreateDatabase(MyDBHandler.DATABASE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        final TextView RegisterPage=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        TextView Text1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        Button Login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.LoginBtn);
        Button GuestLogin=(Button)findViewById(R.id.LoginGuestBtn);
        final EditText LoginUser=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.LoginUser);
        final EditText LoginPass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.LoginPassword);
        RegisterPage.setTextSize(17);
        Text1.setTextSize(17);
        RegisterPage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,RegisterActivity.class));
            }
        });
        GuestLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainPageActivity.class));
            }
        });
        Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(LoginUser.getText().toString().isEmpty()||LoginPass.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                if(_dbHelper.getUserRow(LoginUser.getText().toString(),LoginPass.getText().toString())>0)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "good!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    HashMap<String,String> userInfo  = _dbHelper.getUserInfo(LoginUser.getText().toString(),LoginPass.getText().toString());
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainPageActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("userInfo",userInfo);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error your getting? Don't just tell us it didn't work let us know which kind of error you getting.

Comment: its just doesn't enter to the if that check if the list contains the values that the user entered, every time that i try to login its says that the details are wrong

Comment: Okay Actually I saw your problem. Let me post that answer.

Comment: I posted an answer please check it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is on your `c.getString()` in your whole loop. The first index should be `ID` and it might not be `ID` as well so the proper way is to using

```
c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("yourkey"));
```

Another tips try to not use rawQuery unless you really got no option. You could easily just do a check something like this.

Put this code inside your handler. It might have some syntax error you could try to fix it.

```
 public int getUserRow(String username,String password){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String[] column = {"id"};

    Cursor cursor = db.query(handler.TABLE_USER,column,"User = ? AND Password = ?",new String[]{username,password},null,null,null);
    int row = cursor.getCount();

    return row;
}
```

When you check for login just simply so you don't have actually get the all user from the database to check wether this user is actually exists.

```
if(_dbHelper.getUserRow(yourUsername,yourPassword)){
     //Login here
}
```

One more thing try to keep all database related code inside database class which it is very good pratice and you won't get any confusion after looking back the code.

**Updated:**

Here is the code when you wan to get the login user info add it inside your database helper as well you need to edit the column to match your column

```
 public HashMap<String,String> getUserInfo(String username,String password){
 HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    String[] column = {"usernam","password","rest","of","your","key"};

    Cursor cursor = db.query(handler.TABLE_USER,column,"User = ? AND Password = ?",new String[]{username,password},null,null,null);

    int usernameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("username");
    int passwordIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("password");
    int restIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("rest");
    int ofIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("of");
    int keyIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("key");

    if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
        user.put("username",cursor.getString(usernameIndex));
        user.put("password",cursor.getString(passwordIndex));
        user.put("username",cursor.getString(restIndex));
        user.put("of",cursor.getString(ofIndex));
        user.put("key",cursor.getString(keyIndex));
    }

    return user;
 }
```

So in your if statement try to add this. This code basically help you get user data and pass all the data to your user info activity.

```
if(_dbHelper.getUserRow(yourUsername,yourPassword)){
     HashMap<String,String> userInfo  = _dbHelper.getUserInfo(username,password);
    Intent intent = new Intent(yourContext,YourActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("userInfo",userInfo);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

So now you pass all the data to the other activity you could grab it inside your onCreate.

```
userInfo = (HashMap<String, String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("userInfo");
Log.d("user",userInfo.get("your key"));
```

Comment: um excuse me for being ignorant but I'm a little new to the database and its really hard for me to work with but when how does this check if the user logged in his details if its only return the row number of the entered user

Comment: @NirCohen you being polite bro. So does it help?

Comment: You need to work with HashMap. I update my answer now.

Comment: @NirCohen Updated my code. Basically I do all the job for you LOL

Comment: Thanks for all the hard work but I'm getting really confused.
why do i need to use the hashmap function if i want to check to this specific page directly from the database

Comment: Yea that happen to all developer.The more you pratice the more you not confusing. Kindly accept the question if it really help you out. You get rep as well.

Comment: But its ain't working, or I'm just that idiot that i cant copy this thing in the correct order, can you please explain to me what I need to do, cause i really lost it, sorry.

Comment: Everything in my database works fine, i fixed every syntax error that iv'e had.
but what do i need to put in the login page that after the user will click on the login it will actually read the details from the database and say that everything is good

Comment: You don't need to query from database again. You can pass all the data from the database you get previously from your login page and sent it into your MainPageActivity with using intent. Or you also can pass the login username to your MainPageActivity make a query to get data from database. DId you learn SQL before? I updated my answer you can try to check it

Comment: I'm kind of new to SQL and its really hard to me.
One last thing the getUserrow return int how can you use it in the if statement?

Comment: oh.. sorry forgot if(getUserRow(parameter) > 0)

Comment: Now the app just get crushed, I will post how my code looks now and if you can just tell me what i did wrong..

Comment: You have log cat just observe your log cat